# Call to undefined method from composer added package

Tags: php, laravel, slack-api

I'm trying to use [SlackBot class](https://github.com/mpociot/slackbot#installation-using-composer) with my Laravel 5 app.

But I'm getting this error:

```
Call to undefined method Mpociot\SlackBot\Facades\SlackBot::initialize()
```

This is my controller:

```
use SlackBot;

public function slack_bot()
    {

        $slackbot = new SlackBot();
        $slackbot->initialize('xoxb-XXX');

    }
```

I tried to debug which methods are available with this:

```
$methods = get_class_methods($slackbot);
print_r($methods);
```

and I got this:

```
Array ( [0] => swap [1] => shouldReceive [2] => getFacadeRoot [3] => clearResolvedInstance [4] => clearResolvedInstances [5] => getFacadeApplication [6] => setFacadeApplication [7] => __callStatic )
```

which is very different from the methods defined in github class][2](https://github.com/mpociot/slackbot/blob/master/src/Mpociot/SlackBot/SlackBot.php).

How can I fix this?

---

What I have done:

I'm following this [tutorial](https://github.com/mpociot/slackbot#installation-using-composer)

I ran composer require mpociot/slackbot

And then I added to config/app.php the service provider:

```
Mpociot\SlackBot\SlackBotServiceProvider::class,
```

and the alias / facade:

```
'SlackBot' => Mpociot\SlackBot\Facades\SlackBot::class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a instance of the **Facade** instead of the **real class**.

Replace your

```
    $slackbot = new SlackBot();
    $slackbot->initialize('xoxb-XXX');
```

With:

```
    $slackbot = SlackBot::initialize('token');
```