# Call to a member function hears() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use this [package](https://github.com/mpociot/slackbot) but I'm getting this error:

```
Call to a member function hears() on a non-object
```

This is my code:

```
$slackbot = new SlackBot();
$slackbot = SlackBot::initialize('xoxb');


// give the bot something to listen for.
$slackbot->hears('hello', function (SlackBot $bot, $message) {
   $bot->reply('Hello yourself.');
});
```

How can I fix this?

---

**EDIT**

This is the file I'm in:

routes.php

```
<?php

use SlackBot;

Route::post('/slack', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{

    $payload = $request->all();

    if ( isset($payload['type']) && isset($payload['challenge']) )
    {
        if ($payload['type'] == 'url_verification')
        {
            return $payload['challenge'];
        }
    }

    $slackbot = new SlackBot();
    $slackbot = SlackBot::initialize('xoxb-xxx');


    // give the bot something to listen for.
    $slackbot->hears('hello', function (SlackBot $bot, $message) {
      $bot->reply('Hello yourself.');
    });

});
```

Comment: https://github.com/mpociot/slackbot#basic-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second line is wrong - you should initialise on the created object, not overwrite it.

```
$slackbot = new SlackBot();
$slackbot->initialize('xoxb');
```

Edit: I haven't used SlackBot through a facade myself, but it looks like you should not initialise it since you use a facade. Instead, you should make sure your token is set in the right config file (`services.slack.bot_token`).

Then, instead of e.g.

```
$slackbot->hears(...)
```

you do

```
SlackBot::hears(...)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I will get Call to undefined method Mpociot\SlackBot\Facades\SlackBot::initialize()

Comment: Do you write it exactly like that? The lines are taken straight out of the documentation on the page you linked.

Comment: Yes, I have a question about that too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565186/call-to-undefined-method-from-composer-added-package

Comment: Could you please paste the full code of the file you're in?

Comment: I edited the question with the code. Can you check please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use the facade instead of the actual `SlackBot` class.

Try change:

```
use SlackBot;
```

with:

```
use Mpociot\SlackBot\SlackBot;
```

Or use the `SlackBot::class` to get the full class with namespace:

```
$slackBot = app(SlackBot::class);
$slackBot->initialize('xoxb');
```